# generation of positive numbers in a special case

Tags: prolog

i am searching for a possibility to transform this code

```
zero(0).
positive(X) :- \+ zero(X).
```

so that calls like

```
?- positive(X).
```

will generate values for X.

Actually only calls with specific values for X are tested correctly but no values can be generated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write virtually straightforward

```
positive(1).
positive(X) :- positive(Y), X is Y + 1.
```

and this indeed will work

```
?- positive(X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
etc
```

but have in mind, that being not tail-recursive this algorithm is exponentially complex.
I mean:

```
 ?- time((positive(X),X>4000)).
% 8,010,001 inferences, 3.70 CPU in 3.73 seconds (99% CPU, 2163038 Lips)
X = 4001.
```

Note the time for generation of 4000 positives.

But if we right it like:

```
positive1(X) :- from(1,X).

from(From,From).
from(From,X):-From1 is From + 1, from(From1,X).
```

All works fast now:

```
 ?- time((positive1(X),X>4000)).
% 8,002 inferences, 0.00 CPU in 0.00 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
X = 4001.
```

Comment: Thanks, this is quiet clear to me. But as mentioned above there seems to be no possibility to generate values for X using the negotation. Right?

Comment: I believe your first solution runs in quadratic time rather than exponential.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as posted here won't test anything correctly, except negative numbers, and then only accidentally (even a stopped clock is right twice a day :-) ):

```
positive(X) :- \+ zero(0).
```

The `\+/1` predicate succeeds if there is *no way* to satisfy its argument. In other words, it will yield true whenever `zero(0)` can't be satisfied. But `zero(0)` is *always satisfied* (it's a fact!). So `positive(X)` here will yield false for any X – including 0!

I assume you really meant:

```
positive(X) :- \+ zero(X).
```

which fails too, but in a more interesting way. Remember that `\+/1` fails if there is *any way* to satisfy its argument. If you query:

```
?- positive(1).
```

it will bind X to 1, and see if it's possible to satisfy `zero(X)` with the constraint that X must be 1. It's not, so `positive(1)` will yield true.

However, if you query:

```
?- positive(X).
```

you're asking if it's possible to satisfy `zero(X)` *with no constraints on X*. It *is* possible to do this by binding X to 0, which means `zero(X)` *can* be satisfied for some X – which will cause `\+ zero(X)` to yield false.

A closer step is to try:

```
positive(X) :- X > 0.
```

which takes negative numbers into account as well. This will give the right answer for `positive(1)`, `positive(0)`, and `positive(-1)`. However, it won't generate numbers. If you try this:

```
?- positive(X).
```

you'll get:

```
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

because you haven't said enough about what X is for the `>/2` predicate to take effect – arithmetic operators cannot be invoked on uninstantiated objects (aka free variables, aka what X is in this case). This in general is going to be a problem with your "generate some integers" approach.

You can, however, specify a *particular numeric range* that you want to take values from, and have Prolog proceed from there:

```
positive(X) :- X > 0.
genPositive(X) :- between(-100, 100, X), positive(X).
```

Comment: Thanks, i really meant: positive(X) :- \+ zero(X).
But there seems to be no possibility to generate values for X using the negotation. Right?